# ExpressJS creating multiple JSON objects with helper function

Tags: javascript, json, express, async-await

I'm trying to create multiple JSON objects using an external call out to FourSquare API with different query parameters, but my code keeps returning as a successful response code with no readable results. Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
async function getPlaces(query, lat, lon, clientID, clientSecret, versionDate) {
    const URL = `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=${clientID}&v=${versionDate}&ll=${lat},${lon}&intent=browse&radius=10000&query=${query}&limit=10&client_secret=${clientSecret}`;
    const response = await fetch(URL).catch(e => { console.log(e) });
    const data = await response.json().catch(e => { console.log(e) });

    return data;
}
```

When I call this function to create a JSON object like so

```
const beachData = getPlaces("beaches", lat, lon, clientID, clientSecret, versionDate);
```

It then returns as this:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

I tried this with the same result

```
const beachData = getPlaces("beaches", lat, lon, fourSquareClientID, fourSquareClientSecret, versionDate).then(({ beachData }) => { beachData; });
```

Any guidance on what i'm doing wrong would be HUGELY appreciated. If I'm not totally off the mark I'd like to be able to call on this function a few times and get some JSON objects back I can later combine for the response back to the front end. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how you can know that you need to await the promise returning function `fetch()` yet not know that you need to await the promise returning function `getPlaces()`

Comment: Upon review that was an oversight, haha.Was working late and definitely overlooked that. 

Thanks for pointing that out, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to log the return value of `fetch`;

```
let x = fetch(URL);
console.log(x);
```

You would get:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

So the solution is of course to `await` it:

```
let x = await fetch(URL);
```

Similarly, you need to `await` your function:

```
const beachData = await getPlaces("beaches", lat, lon, clientID, clientSecret, versionDate);
```